# Google search console consider 404 urls as crawl anomaly category and not 404 not found category

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot

I've got a site which we have mention as 404 not found for a few particular pages so that google can consider and push it to Excluded Not found (404) category, but still, google is considering those pages as crawl anomaly category. Please find the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the URL Inspection tool to do a Live Test to confirm that Google is seeing them as 404s.

Comment: When I check on URL inspection tool, I get 
URL is not on Google
This page is not in the index, but not because of an error. See the details below to learn why it wasn't indexed. Learn more

Comment: That implies that Googlebot is not seeing a 404 status code. I can't help much with the details.

Comment: Is that I need to change anything on my end?

Comment: Most likely. You need to make sure your "404 page" also returns a 404 status code in its HTTP header. And it does that for Googlebot.